# Is there Alternative of FILTER function on non office 365 excell users?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm used the Filter to fill in data from sheet to another. Base of the information in **Salesperson_Table6[Unit Size]** which is single cell. When Some people open it on their pc this function is not working and it as **_xlfn._xlws**. add to the start of it. Been try a couple different work around but not seem to be working. Can anyone help? See my function below.

```
=FILTER('50% Offer'!B5:B33,'50% Offer'!A5:A33=Salesperson_Table6[Unit Size],"Not found")
```

I try this

```
=IFERROR(INDEX('50% Offer'!B5:B33,AGGREGATE(15,7,ROW('50% Offer'!A5:A33)/('50% Offer'!A5:A33=C12),ROW($ZZ1))),"")
```

But it return the wrong value, It seem to pick a value 3 row down then one I need  need.

Comment: Try this : `=IFERROR(INDEX('50% Offer'!$B$5:$B$33,AGGREGATE(15,7,(ROW('50% Offer'!$A$5:$A$33)-ROW('50% Offer'!$A$5)+1)/('50% Offer'!$A$5:$A$33=C12),ROW($ZZ1))),"")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX('50% Offer'!$B$5:$B$33,
 AGGREGATE(15,7,(ROW('50% Offer'!$A$5:$A$33)-ROW('50% Offer'!$A$5)+1)/
 ('50% Offer'!$A$5:$A$33=C12),ROW($ZZ1))),"")
```

---

The array needs to return a range of 1,2,3,etc so it refer the matching row values.

This part of the formula does that

```
(ROW('50% Offer'!$A$5:$A$33)-ROW('50% Offer'!$A$5)+1)
```

---